# How to convert eg "40 million" to $40,000,000?

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to covert a numeric string(as shown in the subject) to a proper one like $40,000,000.

Does php offer a function to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's no built-in function for this sort of thing. But once you've got the string converted to a number, you can use `number_format()` to pretty-fy the number with commas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$str = str_replace(' billion','000000000',$str);
$str = str_replace(' million','000000',$str);
$str = str_replace(' thousand','000',$str);
$str = str_replace(' hundred','00'$str);

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');    
$str = money_format('%i',$str);
```