# Convert string word number into string number php

Tags: php, html, web

I have a number that is a string with a value of "53 MILLION".

```
            $number="53 MILLION";
```

I want this number to be 53,000,000. How would go about doing this? I tried using the number_format function but with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

```
$number="53 MILLION";

     $number= str_replace($number, "MILLION", "000,000");

    echo $number; //000,000 instead of 53,000,000
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206581/how-to-convert-eg-40-million-to-40-000-000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on what Jesus said, a simple function to construct these numbers would be:

```
function declare_number($number_string){
    $find_replace = array(
        ' HUNDRED'  =>  '00',
        ' THOUSAND' =>  ',000',
        ' MILLION'  =>  ',000,000',
        ' BILLION'  =>  ',000,000,000'
    );
    return str_ireplace(array_keys($find_replace),$find_replace,$number_string);
}
```

This would also be able to convert 8 hundred thousand = 800,000 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just split your string, search for the "MILLION" substring within your array, then exchange it for "000,000", then put it all back together? I suppose you can use spaces for the split.

Comment: Didn't even think of that. Thanks for the quick reply. Just for future reference, if it was like fifty three million, how would you do it then?

Comment: It would be a matter of making a matrix of word to recognize. fifty = 50, three = 3. I would make an algorythm that recognized the numbers, then multiplied it by "MILLION" (1,000,000). Format whatever comes out.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have million number then use:

```
$number = str_replace(' million', '000000', $number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know PHP but have an algorithm

Algorithm for "53 Million, 2 hundred-thousand, 8 hundred":

Size String Translation Table = [{"Million", 1000000},{"Thousand", 1000}, etc...]
counter = 0
--Scan from top of string to end:
----until comma
------scan integer - "53"
------scan size string - "Million"
------multiply integer by size string translation - "53 * 1000000"
------Add to the main counter - counter += "53000000"
----loop
--end

Answer (score 0):

Depends how example is your question
Your real case could be: 
convert `53 MILLION 39 TOUSEND 334` into `53,039,334` etc.

So the algorithm would be to tokenize a string, wherever a number is available, remember it on stack. Wherever one of `THOUSEND, MILLION, etc.` is available, multiply what you have on stack and add to number. At the end add what is left without multiplying. Then you have the number.

Convert the number into number-string (53039334) and, going from end, after each 3 digits add coma, and here you have what you need :)